Custom drag handle in Flutter
How do I get the drag handle of modal bottom sheet to look like this?:

Here's what I have in my theme:
// ...
bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
      showDragHandle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      dragHandleSize: Size(72.w, 8.h),
      dragHandleColor: kDarkTextColor,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(32),
        ),
      ),
    ),
// ...

And here's how it looks atm:


for this you need to create custom bottomsheet
